# matplotlib plot saved empty

Tags: python, matplotlib

My plot is saved to png without any dots.

This is my code, with the boring stuff cut out:

```py
    import sys
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
    import numpy as np

    region_sales = {
        'region1': {'price': 100, 'volume': 20},
        'region2': {'price': 200, 'volume': 80},
        'region3': {'price': 120, 'volume': 600},
        'region4': {'price': 300, 'volume': 92},
        'region5': {'price': 57, 'volume': 10},
        'region6': {'price': 900, 'volume': 128}
    }

    for region, data in region_sales.items():
        region_name =  region
        volume = data['volume']
        price = data['price']
        plt.scatter(price, volume, marker='o',
                 label=region_name)
        print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(region_name, volume, price))

    plt.legend(numpoints=1)
    plt.xlim(0, 1.8)
    plt.savefig('test.png')
```

The output of this code is:

```
region1 25.666666666666668  800100.0
region2 7374.638676844784   1000000.0
region3 85.78061224489795   850500.0
region4 148.5267175572519   1200000.0
region5 77.74809160305344   1444000.0
region6 634.1374045801526   994900.0
```

And an image is saved to `test.png`, with X and Y axis that match the data, and with a legend that matches the region names. But there are no points on the plot. Just axis, a grid and a legend.

What Am I missing?

Comment: is the image correct if you use `plt.show()`?

Comment: @LeiYang no. It's exactly like the saved image.

Comment: can you paste a copy and run example (along with the data)?

Comment: @LeiYang sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: i mean you include the (minimal fake) data in the question, so every one can copy the code and reproduce the issue. only when we reproduced can we solve.

Comment: Hi @summerbulb remove the plt.xlim(0,1.8) i dont know why did you add it. But its the one that causing the issue